# inheriting from a class declarations in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

When you want to inherit from a class in C++, is it illegal to have std declared in the first line below?

```
#ifndef HWEXCEPTION_H
#define HWEXCEPTION_H

#include <stdexcept>


class HWException : public std::run_time_error
{
    void testException(int num);
};

#endif
```

vs

```
using std::run_time_error
class MyClass : public run_time_error
```

This is assuming you have #include  at the top.  I get compile errors for having std::run_time_error, but do not seem to by doing it the second way and was wondering why.

```
 error C2039: 'run_time_error' : is not a member of 'std'
 'run_time_error' : base class undefined
1>main.cpp
 error C2039: 'run_time_error' : is not a member of 'std'
 error C2504: 'run_time_error' : base class undefined
```

Comment: +1 Could it have used a '?'? Sure, but it's a legitimate question and shouldn't have been downvoted because of an error in punctuation.

Comment: @Suma "is it illegal to have std declared in the first line below" seems like a clear enough question, even if it is missing a question mark.

Comment: If you get an error for the first version (which is preferable, see Neil's answer), then this error is not in the code you've shown. If you can't fix this, I suggest you put a ten-liner (necessary includes and all, fully compilable except for the error you're seeing) which we can paste into our editors and try ourselves into a new question and ask for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are legal. But assuming this is in a header file, you should not use the using directive version, as it places the name in the global namespace, which may cause problems for users of your header.

**Edit:** Just noticed that you have the class name wrong:

```
#include <stdexcept>
class MyClass : public std::runtime_error {
};
```

is what you need.